# Problem with saving the data from an API response to a global variable

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, axios, fetch

I am complete newbie in JavaScript and Still understanding async and await programs

I have a program with a axios resquest.

```
axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
})
```

The request is working fine and I am getting the Data . I want to save this data to an external variable. Like this.

```
let data;

axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  data = response.data;
})

console.log(data);
```

But this is showing data is undefined. Any suggestions or solutions

I have tried using async and await functions but couldn't lead to a solution.